# SQL Query; Locate and Disable

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery, qsqltablemodel

I am new at SQL, including performing queries. Everyday, our organization sends a list of employees that were terminated in a listed format.

We get a text file everyday with a list of employee ID's that were terminated, that we need to deactivate in our application's database. I know this is still manual, but I think it is a good start for some automation. We essentially need to do two tasks, find the user in the database in two locations, and deactivate them.

Maybe a function?

**1.** On the `dbo.EnterpriseUser` table, we need the code to find the user by looking for the `IVRID` (Which is the employee's ID sent to us in the listed format) and then update the `IsActive` field from `1` to `0`, and then update the `LastModDate` to the current date and time using the same format. Below is the example table I am working with, sorry if the formatting is not correct.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EnterpriseUser (
    `EnterpriseUserID` INT,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `LastName` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `IVRID` INT,
    `IsActive` INT,
    `LastModDate` DATETIME
 );
 INSERT INTO EnterpriseUser VALUES
    (6,'Robert','Andrews',2,1,'2018-07-11 13:01:54.670000');
```

**2.** The second table `dbo.Staff` must be properly updated as well for the application. My only problem is that to find the record to update, I have to use the `EnterpriseUserID` field from `dbo.EnterpriseUser` as it is now in the `StaffID` field on the `dbo.Staff` table.

On that row, the `LastModDate` must be changed to current date and the `IsActive` must change from `1` to `0`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Staff (
    `StaffID` INT,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `LastName` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `LastModDate` DATETIME,
    `IsActive` INT
);
INSERT INTO Staff VALUES
    (6,'Robert','Andrews','2018-07-11 13:01:54.670000',1);
```

Comment: Great formatting for your second question.  Thanks for the DDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer question #1:

```
UPDATE EnterpriseUser
SET IsActive = 0,  LastModDate = NOW()
WHERE 
  IVRID = 2;
```

To answer question #2:

```
UPDATE Staff
SET IsActive = 0,  LastModDate = NOW()
WHERE StaffID = 
 (SELECT EnterpriseUserID 
  FROM EnterpriseUser 
  WHERE IVRID = 2);
```

If I was building these, I would likely have a script that ran through the text file.

You can combine these into a barebones procedure like such:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE termination (IN inIVRID INT)
BEGIN 
  UPDATE EnterpriseUser
  SET IsActive = 0,  LastModDate = NOW()
  WHERE 
  IVRID = inIVRID;
  UPDATE Staff
  SET IsActive = 0,  LastModDate = NOW()
  WHERE StaffID = 
   (SELECT EnterpriseUserID 
    FROM EnterpriseUser 
    WHERE IVRID = inIVRID);  
  COMMIT;  
END$$
```

Comment: The updates worked perfect, thank you! However, I am having an issues trying to run the procedure. Can you please let me know how to run the procedure through a text file? Like in the procedure, where does the data for `IVRID` go? Just trying to learn as much as I can!

Comment: For a procedure, you would just use `CALL termination(2)`.  The procedure might need a little bit of tweaking as MySQL is not my primary engine of expertise.  To run over a text file, I would likely use some scripting language (Python most likely) to iterate over all of the lines in the daily text file.  I would then insert the IVRID values into the SQL code above and execute them against the database.